# How to show my wordpress admin username & password?

Tags: password, username

When I created my WordPress website, I was given an admin login username and password. However, I have forgotten both. What is the procedure to find my WordPress admin login username and password from the file or database?

Comment: Check `wp_users` table in your database for Username/Email and then you can use forgot password option.

Answer (score 3):

Login your cPanel after that click **database->phpMyAdmin**
after that click your database that has install your WordPress, you find "**wp_users**" data table and then click **edit** after that select **user_pass->md5** and write new password this input field, after this process click "**Go**" button and login your WordPress admin panel. I think it's work

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can see your username but can't see your password. However, you can reset your current password.

Simply, Click on **phpMyAdmin** option and this will open in new tab and here you need to select your WordPress database. (You can verify your database details from **wp-config.php** file)

You will see the list of all the tables in your WordPress database. Now you have to look for the “**{table-prefix}_users**’ (by default table will be **wp_users**) table in the list and click on the browse link placed next to it with many other options.

You will now see a number of rows in your WordPress users table. Click on the edit button placed next to the username where you want to change the password.

You will see a form filled up with all the user information fields needed.

Now, the major step of this method is to delete the value in the **user_pass** field and replace it with a new password. You will find a function column placed right before the null value column. You need to click on it and select **MD5** from the drop-down menu and click the **GO** option.

Now you can visit /wp-admin and enter your username and password :).

Comment: How is this answer different from that of @Himadree ?